# How do I add this custom HTML above my WordPress </head> tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I tried inserting this HTML code in my `functons.php` file in the `enqueue scripts` following the [directions](https://bibles.org/pages/highlighter) "To use the Highlighter on your website, add the following line of HTML just before the closing `</head>` tag on every page on your website that should have Scripture references found"

```
<script id="bw-highlighter-config">
(function(w, d, s, e, id) {
  w._bhparse = w._bhparse || [];
  function l() {
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    var n = d.createElement(s), x = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    n.id = id; n.async = true; n.src = '//bibles.org/linker/js/client.js';
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(n, x);
  }
  (w.attachEvent) ? w.attachEvent('on' + e, l) : w.addEventListener(e, l, false);
})(window, document, 'script', 'load', 'bw-highlighter-src');
</script>
```

Here is what my enqueue section looks like in `functions.php` I tried pasting the above HTML right before the ending add_action function, but then I was left with two add_action functions and my site did not load correctly?

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function west_scripts() {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'west-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

        if ( get_theme_mod('body_font_name') !='' ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'west-body-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' . esc_attr(get_theme_mod('body_font_name')) );
        } else {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'west-body-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,500italic,500');
        }

        if ( get_theme_mod('headings_font_name') !='' ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'west-headings-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' . esc_attr(get_theme_mod('headings_font_name')) ); 
        } else {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'west-headings-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700');
        }

        wp_enqueue_style( 'west-fontawesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/font-awesome.min.css' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'west-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20130115', true );

        if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
                wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
        }

        if ( get_theme_mod('blog_layout') == 'masonry-layout' && (is_home() || is_archive()) ) {
                wp_enqueue_script( 'west-masonry-init', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry-init.js', array('jquery-masonry'),'', true );
        }

        wp_enqueue_script( 'west-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'west-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'west_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Wordpress, you need to add some special code to the end of your functions.php file to tell Wordpress to add your HTML above the `</head>` tag:

```
add_action('wp_head','add_bw_highlighter');

function add_bw_highlighter() { ?>
    <script id="bw-highlighter-config">
    (function(w, d, s, e, id) {
      w._bhparse = w._bhparse || [];
      function l() {
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        var n = d.createElement(s), x = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        n.id = id; n.async = true; n.src = '//bibles.org/linker/js/client.js';
        x.parentNode.insertBefore(n, x);
      }
      (w.attachEvent) ? w.attachEvent('on' + e, l) : w.addEventListener(e, l, false);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'load', 'bw-highlighter-src');
    </script>
<?php }
```